# Using Python cffi for introspection

Tags: json, rpc, python-cffi

I'm contemplating using Python's `cffi` module as part of a Remote Procedure Call package: you create a single `<mymodule>.h` file and use `cffi` to generate the JSON encoders and decoders between the two endpoints.

To do this, I'd use `cffi` to parse the typedefs, the structs and the function signatures, which I'd then use to create the encoders and decoders for the JSON code.

I can see how to get `cffi`'s internal model of a typedef, e.g.:

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> import pprint
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>> ffi.cdef("""
typedef enum { LED_HEAT, LED_FAN} led_id_t;
void set_led(led_id_t led_id, bool on);
""")
>>> led_id_type = ffi.typeof('led_id_t')
>>> led_id_type.elements
{1: 'LED_FAN', 0: 'LED_HEAT'}
```

Question: I know that `cffi` has a model for the signature of the `set_led()` function.  What `cffi` functions give me access to that model?

### Update

By groveling over the cffi sources, I see that I can do the following:

```
>>> x = ffi._parser._declarations['function set_led']
>>> x
(<void(*)(led_id_t, _Bool)>, 0)
>>> type(x[0])
<class 'cffi.model.FunctionPtrType'>
>>> x[0].args
(<led_id_t>, <_Bool>)
>>> type(x[0][0])
<class 'cffi.model.EnumType'>
```

... which gets me pretty much what I want.  Is there a published API for going that (or at least something that doesn't dig so deeply into the internals)?

Comment: Does `ffi.typeof('set_led')` give you the information you want?  Specifically, the attributes `args` and `result`, as I think they are called.

Comment: @ArminRigo I tried that: `ffi.typeof('set_led')` => `KeyError: 'set_led'` and `cffi.CDefError: unknown identifier 'set_led'`

Comment: Ah.  Then I fear the answer is no, I don't think there is support.  Maybe `ffi.typeof()` should be improved to work in this case, and also `ffi.list_functions()` should be added to get the list of function names declared so far.

Comment: Thanks.  For now I can work around it by digging into the unpublished API.